# Which is correct — 'longer than it otherwise would' OR 'longer than it would otherwise'

Tags: grammar

Which of the following sentences is correct, and what is the underlying grammar rule?

> The roads are rough, so the journey takes a little longer **than it otherwise would.**

> The roads are rough, so the journey takes a little longer **than it would otherwise.**

Many thanks,
JJ

Comment: I'm not sure about rules - I think this is an adverb (otherwise) in front of or after the verb (would).

Comment: It's purely a matter of personal choice.